# MongoError: no se pudo conectar al servidor [localhost: 27017]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ubuntu, mongodb

Cuando escribo en la línea de comandos [mongo](/questions/tagged/mongo) me devuelve este error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-01T11:42:17.843+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-05-01T11:42:17.843+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

---

Necesito acceder a mis colecciones de bases de datos.

No creo que sea un error de instalación porque antes funcionaba.

¡De antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Que sistema operativo estas usando??

Comment: Hola Raul, estoy usando ubuntu

Comment: Que pone `systemctl status mongodb` en la terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

este error suele presentarse cuando no hemos inicializado el servidor de la base de datos.

El comando mongo no es la base de datos, es solo un cliente en el shell. Los pasos  serían.

1) abrir dos terminales.

2) en uno de ellos ejecutar mongod (con los parámetros necesarios, como el puerto...), esto ejecuta el servidor de mongodb. Por ejemplo

```
mongod --port 27017
```

la consola debe quedar en espera por conexiones así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si da error el servidor no quedará inicializado y por tanto el comando mongo nunca va a ser ejecutado exitosamente.

3) en el otro terminal (una vez que se ha cargado el servidor) ejecutas mongo y en teoria ya no debe arrojarte error.

```
mongo
```

Espero sea tu error.

acá puedes ver la documentación para installar y ejecutar mongodb en diferentes plataformas https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/

Comment: Hola Clay, acabo de intentarlo otra vez probando tus pasos, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error..

Comment: Hola, (mira la actualización del paso dos) ese error es por que no hay servidor de base de datos  montado, los pasos que puse son genèricos y depende de la plataforma que estés usando (por eso puse el link de la documentación oficial). Cuando hagas el paso dos, asegurate de que el servidor quede montado, dirá " waiting for connections on port 27017" si no es así y te lanza algùn error tienes que leer que error es y corregirlo...  Sí aun no puedes ejecutarlo, recolecta más información y actualiza tu pregunta con esa información nueva para saber más a detalle. @MariferVillarroel

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar lo siguiente en este orden:

sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair

sudo service mongodb start

En ocasiones demora un poco en reiniciar el servicio.